# Selenium IDE skips certain fields

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE to test our website/application. I have noticed that there are specific fields on which Selenium gets stuck. At any test speed, when Selenium gets to that field in the testing it gives out the error that it cannot find the ID. But then I double click on the test line it then goes through. In other words, Selenium IDE can find the ID when I double click on the test line, but not when it is automatic.

Moreover, it is always with the same specific fields. 95% it finds, but a few it gets stuck on in automatic mode.

Also, something similar. I have a specific page where you type data into a series of textboxes. For those specific textboxes it always skips a few of them when in automatic mode. No problem when I double click it. Only when automatic. But all other textboses are fine.

And this occurs even at the slowest speed.

Thank you.

Comment: Let me guess. your site uses JSF and each time you run the app with new fields, it generated new IDs and tests stop working. Is that the case?

Comment: Not at all. Its the same ID each time. Moreover, manually double clicking on the test line works fine. It only fails when its automatic. Immediately after it fails I just double click on the line and it works!